# Vim zencoding - Tagging visual lines

Tags: vim, emmet

Very simple I guess but I cannot get what I perceive to be the correct behavior out of zencoding in vim.

So what I am doing is.

```
1) selecting using visual a who line. 
2) Using <C-e> (rebound) to use zencoding.
3) supply the tags to apply and enter.
```

What happens is saying using h2 occurs with all.

```
<h2>
 My text
</h2>
```

However I want it like.

```
<h2>My Text</h2>
```

How can I get it like that?

Comment: Go to first line ant type `3J` to join 3 lines.

Comment: Latest version of zencoding-vim support visual selection. please try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer if selecting a line in vim with V (shift+v) zencoding completes a block encoding so "some text" becomes:

```
<h1>
  some text
</h1>
```

where as using the singular v and then manually selecting text using h,j,k,l the result is inline:

```
<h1>some text</h1>
```

If anyone has any other neat tricks let me know.